# MySQL REGEXP and repeated words

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a specified problem.

I have, for example: `Hello little, hello red, sometime and now`.

I need regexp what will be match only if the clause contains both `hello` and `red`.

I have complete a regexp `((hello|red).*){2}()*` what will work only if in clause one word `hello` and one word `red`, but in my clause two words `hello` and `regexp` will work without word `red`, what wrong:(

I need regexp what will match only if cause contain word `hello` and word `red` and not depend of repeat one of them.

Please help.

Thx.

Comment: Your regular expression works because `hello` is indeed found twice, you did not require `red` specifically to be there, but either `hello` or `red`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, one would use [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this task, but MySQL's regex engine doesn't support them.

Therefore, your only option (if you want to do this in a single regex) is to handle both variations (`hello` after `red` or `hello` before `red`) "manually":

```
hello.*red|red.*hello
```

For two "search words", that's probably acceptable - it doesn't scale nicely, though.

Your regex `((hello|red).*){2}()*` is a bit strange; it means

```
(            # Start of group:
 (hello|red) # Match either hello or red
 .*          # Match any number of characters
){2}         # Match this group twice
()*          # Match the empty string any number of times...
```

so this matches `hello foo hello` or `red bar red` as well.

Comment: I think use what:)) Apparently no over way. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it'll solve your problem but here is my solution:

```
.*(hello.*red|red.*hello).*
```

Here is an online demo of it with complex explanation of how does it really works:
http://regex101.com/r/eL3wA0

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what you want to do, but I believe regex is an overkill for the task.

How about a simple:

```
WHERE col LIKE "%red%"
    AND col LIKE "%hello%"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for my task what not applicable. But thx any way.